# Crear Timer en tiempo de ejecución c#

Tags: c#, timer

Buenas noches quisiera que me ayudaran con el siguiente problema: tengo un botón en el cual creo un label y un timer en tiempo de ejecución lo que quisiera es que al crearlos se inicie un contador diferente en cada label,
mi código es el siguiente:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    string nuevolabel;
    int posx, con;
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Name = "label"+con.ToString();
        lb.Font = new Font(lb.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        lb.Location = new Point(posx, 45);
        posx += 50;
        nuevolabel = lb.Name.ToString();
        lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 40);
        lb.AutoSize = false;
        lb.Text = "1";
        Controls.Add(lb);
        con++;
        Timer tm = new Timer();
        tm.Interval = 1000;
        tm.Tick += new EventHandler(EventoT_Click);
        tm.Start();
    }
    private void EventoT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
    // el nombre del label es el problema ya que cada vez que creo uno nuevo se almacena en la variable label 
    // y como todos los eventos toman los mismos parametros el valor que toman es el del ultimo label creado
    // y los label anteriores dejan de incrementarse
        Label label= this.Controls.Find(nuevolabel, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
        Double val = Convert.ToDouble(label.Text.ToString());
        val=val+1;
        label.Text = val.ToString();
    }
```

este código no hace lo que yo quisiera ya que el nuevo timer que creo se ejecuta en el label nuevo y no en el que estaba trabajando esto es por que el evento del timer toma la variable que contiene el nombre del label y ese nombre es el que se va creando y yo lo que quiero es que cada timer se ejecute en su respectivo label ya intente guardarlos en una lista y recorrerlos a la hora de crear los controles pero lo que hace es ejecutar todos los timer en todos los labes, yo lo que quisiera saber es si hay alguna forma de que cada evento trabaje con sus respectivos parámetros o algo parecido, e leído algo de delegados pero no logro implementar lo que yo quiero, les agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido @JoseAntonioLemaVargas a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque no lo creas, tu codigo esta bien. Esta generando un timer por label.

El problema es que no estas reconociendo que label esta ejecutando cada timer.

En tu codigo haces esto:

```
private void EventoT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
// el nombre del label es el problema ya que cada vez que creo uno nuevo se almacena en la variable label 
// y como todos los eventos toman los mismos parametros el valor que toman es el del ultimo label creado
// y los label anteriores dejan de incrementarse
    Label label= this.Controls.Find(nuevolabel, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    Double val = Convert.ToDouble(label.Text.ToString());
    val=val+1;
    label.Text = val.ToString();
}
```

Cuando haces:

```
Label label= this.Controls.Find(nuevolabel, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
```

No estas buscando el label que disparo el evento, si no que estas buscando el label en la colección controles que se llame como el ultimo que creaste.

Si vos queres ubicar el label de este timer, vamos a tener que usar alguna estrategia que nos permita ubicar el label.

Podriamos generar un diccionario cuya key fuera este objeto, y su contenido el nombre del label

```
Dictionary<Timer,String> d = new Dictionary<Timer,String>();
```

Y cuando ocurre el evento tick, buscar el objeto que genero el evento y ubicar el label

```
Timer t = (Timer) sender;
String NombreDelLabel = Dictionary[t];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder tratare de implementar la información que me diste